# can this be converted to a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

Out of pure curiosity I was just wondering if the following snipped can be converted to a Linq routine ? Just curious of what linq is capable.

```
  var k = str1.IndexOf(str2.Substring(i, 1)) + str1.IndexOf(key.Substring(i, 1));
```

the full code being:

```
for (int i=0;i<str2.Length;i++)
{
var k = str1.IndexOf(str2.Substring(i, 1)) +       str1.IndexOf(key.Substring(i, 1));
if (k >= 36) {k = k - 36;}
result += str1.Substring(k, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you provied a sample data from variables? **str1**, **str2** and **key**?

Comment: Yes it is, But why on earth someone need to do that? Do they have put a gun on your head and want you to do it in LINQ otherwise they will kill you? :D

Comment: the variables are just random string with no purpose, they can be anything

Comment: @sean If they can bee anything, so your code will fail easy, because you are looping through str2 characters and using substring in key string, if str2 is bigger than key string, it will throw an exception. Whats the purpose of this method?

Answer (score 2):

Strings have "sequence processing" built in and the code that you have works. Even if you translate it to LINQ the code looks kind of the same, just a little bit worse.

LINQ does not have `IndexOf` built in, though. You would need to write that. `Substring` can be emulated using `Skip` and `Take`, but those do not perform range validation which can hide bugs.

This is not a good case for LINQ.

Comment: I know sometimes it better to use "this method" rather than "that method" but its just curiosity, im simply wondering if it can actually do it .. how it looks.. i find it somehow interesting

Comment: Sure, I get that. Feel free to copy some IndexOf code that works for IEnumerable from somewhere and use it as an experiment. The result is probably terrible code :)

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not intended to create that queries. It's most commonly used to build queries on **data generic collections**. For this example you should't use Linq. It's better to leave it in the form which you introduced. Performance tip: use **StringBuilder**. More here:
http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-performance